# Mouse pointer stuck but computer completely functional

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

As I am writing this question, my Ubuntu 18.04 has again hit the problem that it often hits:

1. it is completely functional. I can open and close applications with a breeze through my keyboard.
2. I can move the mouse pointer around.
3. The mouse pointer icon is stuck, and clicking the mouse pointer anywhere does not do any interaction it at all. For example, clicking on the Chrome icon won't launch it, won't in fact do anything, however, launching it via the keyboard works. The same applies to any mouse clicks, they don't simply occur, as if nothing was clicked.

I checked the memory usage via `top` and it doesn't seem to be very high in total (<50%). What's the problem and how to fix it?

---

List of the gnome extensions I am using:

```
drwxrwxr-x 5 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:22 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com 
drwxrwxr-x 7 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:25 dynamic-panel-transparency@rockon999.github.io
drwxrwxr-x 5 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:29 gnome-shell-screenshot@ttll.de
drwxrwxr-x 2 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:29 remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com
```

Output of `free -h` (not at the time my mouse pointer was stuck):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.3G        1.8G        255M         70M        1.3G        1.3G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

`sudo lshw -C memory`:

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Insyde
       physical id: 0
       version: F.10
       date: 07/25/2016
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1d
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 4GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: HMT451S6DFR8A-PB
          vendor: Hynix
          physical id: 0
          serial: 065580E3
          slot: Bottom-Slot 1(Left)
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2018-07-12 13:19+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18719) [empty]
          product: Empty
          vendor: Empty
          physical id: 1
          serial: Empty
          slot: Bottom-Slot 2(Right)
```

Comment: Do you have any GNOME extensions installed? Show me `ls -al ~/.local/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: @heynnema yes, I have a couple of them. They are: 
`drwxrwxr-x 5 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:22 dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 7 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:25 dynamic-panel-transparency@rockon999.github.io
drwxrwxr-x 5 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:29 gnome-shell-screenshot@ttll.de
drwxrwxr-x 2 gt gt 4096 Dec 17 17:29 remove-dropdown-arrows@mpdeimos.com`
Note that they were in `~/.local` *`/share`* `/gnome-shell/extensions`. However, I am pretty sure I have had this issue since the past month, like since December 1st, well before I installed any gnome-extension.

Comment: I don't see any one extension that is suspect. Dash to Panel or Dynamic Panel Transparency might be candidates though. Since the problem occurs weekly, temporarily turn off ALL extensions and see if the problem goes away. I bet it will. Then add one extension back at a time until the problem reoccurs again, and that's the bad one. Show me the output of `free -h`.. put the output as an edit to your question please.

Comment: FYI: turn off extensions at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, I might have been unclear. By once every week, I meant the problem occurs somewhat frequently, not often, but not rare either. It wasn't exact, and I didn't count it. I'll edit that part of the question. Also, I'll repeat that I've been facing this problem since the start of this month, much earlier than I installed any gnome extension.

Comment: It still think it may be an extension problem... I did look at your `free -h` output, and it looks a little strange... show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Also, your swap file is too small.

Comment: @heynnema Alright, I added that output too. What's strange about that `free -h` output though?

Comment: `free -h` only shows 3.3G of RAM, but your `lshw` correctly shows 4G. You probably have shared video memory that accounts for the other 700K. Does that sound familiar? Without seeing `free -h` or `top` when the system is fully busy, I can't tell if your problem is due to small RAM or small swap, or something else. FYI: if you ever decide to buy more RAM, make sure that optimally it's a 4G stick, so that you'll get the speed advantage of "memory interleaving". Right now, I'd still increase your swap from 2G to 4G. I'd still explore the GNOME extensions possibility.